# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline fails if branch does not have jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have a legacy build system on which I want to incrementally add multibranch pipeline support to branches so all branches will build and test for Continuous Integration. However ... old branches do not have a jenkinsfile present and a multibrach pipeline build fails with FileNotFoundException.

The pipeline works just fine on my new branches. It finds the jenkinsfile and runs the build fine. Can I have the pipeline filter out or ignore older branches that do not have a jenkinsfile?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins you have? in my setup, the branches without jenkinsfile are just ignored and never built.